# xamarin forms rounded edge progress bar and gradient color

Tags: xamarin.forms, progress-bar, gradient, rounded-corners

Can anyone help with some tips to create a **Progress Bar** similare to the progress bar in the picture in both android and IOS.

Any tip or trick could be helpful.

[ProgressBar picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQGXj.png)

Answer (score 0):

I know that on android applications in Xamarin Forms, the color of a progress bar is tied to the value of colorAccent in the styles file in the Android Resources folder.

To make the progress bar white you could make the colorAccent line like this:

```
<item name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</item>
```

A warning with doing this, it will also change the colors of other views accent colors such as Switches.

To add the number next to the progress bar, it is easiest to do that with a label that is positioned next to the progress bar.  Then in your code, whenever you change the value of the progress bar, you can also change the Text of the label.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to round the corners, I think you would need to do that with a custom renderer.

Comment: Yes i have tried a custom renderer with android style.xml file.